# Regex Routing - rule not being found

Tags: zend-framework

I'm defining regex routes for cleaning up my URLS. The idea is that all pages added by the user will be use the URL www.example.com/page-slug rather than using the actual controller, www.example.com/userpages/page-slug. Other pages will follow the standard module:controller:action routing scheme.

I'm trying to aceive this using router precedence.

I have defined the scheme below..

```
class Default_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap{  

protected function _initRoute() {

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default

    $route['index'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '/',
        array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );
    $route['contact'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        'contact/(\d+)',
        array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'contact',
        'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );
    $route['research'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        'research/(\d+)',
        array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'research',
        'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );
    $route['account'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        'account/(\d+)',
        array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'account',
        'action'     => 'index'
        )
    );
    $route['userpages'] = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '/(.+)',
        array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'userpages',
        'action'     => 'index'
        ),
        array(
        'slug' => 1
        ),
        '%s'
    );

    $router->addRoute('userpages',     $route['userpages']);
    $router->addRoute('contact',       $route['contact']);
    $router->addRoute('research',      $route['research']);
    $router->addRoute('account',       $route['account']);
    $router->addRoute('index',         $route['index']);

}

}
```

Things are generally working OK with the router precedence ensuring that index/account/research/contact pages are picking up the correct controller. However, when attempting to go to a URL covered by the "userpages" route e.g. "about-us", final catch all route is not being found resulting in...

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (about-us) 
.
.
.
Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'about-us',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong here? It seems to me that the regex is correct "/(.+)" should be catching eveything that is not the index page.

EDIT: @phatfingers, OK you're right, I've edited "\d+" to ".+" to catch one or more of any character. The problem persists. In fact before changing the regex, I tried the URL www.example.com/52, and got the same error - "Invalid controller specified (52)". After the change - with code as per the edited snippet above, the rule is still failing to find any matches.

Comment: The regex "(\d+)" matches digits only.  The example URL, "www.example.com/page-slug" doesn't end with digits.

Comment: thanks for the observation @phatfingers, see my edit above - the rule is still not matching where expected

Comment: I think you have to drop the forward slash in the 'userpages' regex, i.e. just `('.+)`

Comment: @Arian World, thanks. I have clearly misinterpreted the way the regex parameter works. Your suggestion works, but right now, I'm unsure why. I think another look at the manual is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the forward slash in the 'userpages' regex, i.e. just ('.+)

The quote is straight from the manual [Zend Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) and Router_Regex but afaik it also applies to all the routes.

> Note: Leading and trailing slashes are trimmed from the URL in the
>   Router prior to a match. As a result, matching the URL
>   http://domain.com/foo/bar/, would involve a regex of foo/bar, and not
>   /foo/bar.